# Connecting to Openfire using Icelink

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I’m trying to build a **voip** app with `openfire` on server-side, `Icelink` on client-side in `xamarin` android.
The problem is the `openfire` client(running on port 5222) does not respond at all even from the local host.
For example when i try `192.168.1.xx:5222` in my browser, it is always in acquire stat and does not response anything.
I have checked all the primitive things and tested the server with `Spark` and it works fine!

Comment: Can you plz elaborate the issue a bit more? "For example when i try 192.168.1.xx:5222 in my browser, it is always in acquire stat and does not response anything." What are your expectations here, what should display on 192.168.1.xx:5222?

Comment: It must return an "ok" value which it did for just one time!